# How to make a iMACROS that runs every 3 hour?

Tags: imacros

I've been having issue to find out how to make a macro on iMACROS on chrome, that could allow me automatize one macro.

My goal is to find how could I make my macro to run every 3/4 hour, what it make this macro is to clean the cache from my webpage (I need to make it every 3/4 hours).

**Here is my code:**

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://MyWEBSITe
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:System
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Cache<SP>Management
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Flush<SP>Cache<SP>Storage
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:OK
```

Comment: Meant as a "rhetorical" Qt maybe, check the iMacros Forum where your Qt has already been asked and answered 20 times... - And yep, @macroscripts's Answer is indeed the quick and dirty Solution... - Hum, except that 3600 x3 = 10,800 Sec (and not 2700)... Hum, OK, "3/4 hour" <> "3/4 hours", then OK, 2700 Sec is maybe correct indeed... (if you meant 45 Min)...

Comment: But, hum-hum, without "s" I would indeed also go for the 'WAIT' I think, but with "s" then rather for CLI + your OS Task Manager...

Comment: Oops, sorry: "Task Manager" = "Task Scheduler"...

Comment: Hum, "every 3 hours" in Thread Title..., then the 'WAIT' is not a very "clean" Solution, I would think... Kind of a "pity" to have to "sacrifice" a CR Instance/Profile for that... - FCI not mentioned but you seem to be using v10.0.5 for CR 'Free'/'PE', for which CLI (Command Line Interface) Support is a bit "limited", and you'd need to embed your Macro in some local HTML Page like documented in the Wiki (https://wiki.imacros.net/Webextensions#Command_Line_Support) or in this Thread for example (https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=21954) with a slightly different Method...

Comment: You might consider rather dedicating a FF Profile (FF v55.0.3 or Pale Moon v28.x) + iMacros for FF v8.9.7 that fully supports CLI and running your Macro every 3 Hours from your OS Task Scheduler from a '.BAT' File or 'cron' Job... (Many Examples on the iMacros Forum if you search for "bat/batch"...)

Answer (score 0):

Add waiting time

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://MyWEBSITe
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:System
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Cache<SP>Management
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Flush<SP>Cache<SP>Storage
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:OK
WAIT SECONDS=2700
```